# How to get content type stats into view

Tags: views

Hi I am a new drupal coder working a project and making fairly good progress with views an such but i am having a hard time with a specific request.

I need to build a block to display a list of stats in various locations

number of registered users

number of tags uses on a certain content type

number of posts of a certain content type

number of comments contained on all posts of a certain content type

number  of revisions on all a certain content type

I am not sure how to get the above data into views.

I would greatly appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know from your question, which part you're having a hard time with exactly, so I'll just be general in my response:

Typically, when you set up a view, you're getting either users, or content, or terms, or comments -- those are very different types of data.  Typically, a view will not give you all those things together in one display.

So my suggestion would be to try to get each of the different stat types in separate views, and then you can always combine multiple views in one page or block for display purposes at the end...

So, when you start creating a new view, select the correct type of content to show on the first view setup screen (I'm assuming you're using Drupal 7 - it's always useful to specify in your question or via a tag). In Drupal 7, that first view setup screen will prompt you for the type of data you're going to be displaying, so select '**Content**' for the revisions stat view or '**Taxonomy term**' for the tagging stat view or '**Users**' for the user stat view, etc.

Then go from there... just try to do these separately and that would be easiest!!

Comment: Thank you for your assistance I will try your suggest and break each item out into there own view